# How to make a layout where the left side will be fixed for an image, the right for a button, and the center or middle place for text?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making a food order layout where the left side will contain images, the middle contains text, and the right side is for an add button.

The image is fixed on the left side, but the button is moving according to the middle text length. So I want to fix this layout:

[image]

Where the button will also be fixed on the right side, the same as the left side image, and doesn't depend on the middle test length.

If the text is long, then the text will be moved to the next line.

**Foodlist.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Foodlist.css";
import { useStateValue } from "../../StateProvider";

function Foodlist({ id, title, rating, image, price, info, stock, nostock  }) {
 
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  // console.log("This is the basket >>>", basket);


  const addToBasket = () => {
    // dispatch the item into the data layer
      dispatch({
          type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
          item: {
              id: id,
              title: title,
              info: info,
              image: image,
              price: price,
              stock: stock,
              nostock: nostock,
              rating: rating,
          },
      });
  };


  return (
    <div className="food">
      <div className="food__details">
        <img src={image} alt="" />
        {/* <button onClick={addToBasket} style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
          <strong style={{fontSize: 20}}>+ </strong>
          Add
        </button> */}
      </div>

      <div className="food__title">
        <div className="food__info__layout">
          <p style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{title}</p>
          <p className="food__info">
            <small>₹ </small>
            <strong style={{fontSize: 14 ,fontWeight: 100}}>{price}</strong>
          </p>
        </div>

        <button onClick={addToBasket} style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
          <strong style={{fontSize: 20}}>+ </strong>
          Add
        </button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Foodlist
```

**Foodlist.css**

```
.food {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.food__details{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.food__details > img {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* 
.food__details > button {
  background: gold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
} */


.food__info__layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.food__info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: auto;
  /* margin-bottom: 5px; */
}

.food__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.food__title > button {
  background: gold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the image at the left and the button at the right, no matter the length of the text in between, you can set `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto` on a wrapper that contains them as direct children.

Find below a simplified version of what you want. Notice I simplified the HTML structure. If you copy past, don't forget to change `class` to `className` for React.

```css
.food {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.food > img {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.food .food__title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.food .food__button {
  background: gold; border: none; cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px; font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="food">
  <img
    class="food__image"
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661956602116-aa6865609028?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80"
    alt=""
  />

  <div class="food__desc">
    <h2 class="food__title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h2>
    <p class="food__info">
      <small>₹ </small>
      <strong>12</strong>
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="food__button">
    <strong>+ </strong>
    Add
  </button>
</div>
```